# Layer "sequential" expects 1 input(s), but it received 37 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, chatbot

I was trying to train a tensorflow model in order to make a chatbot. That being said the problem I am encountering is this:

```
ValueError: Layer "sequential" expects 1 input(s), but it received 37 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:3' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:4' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:5' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:6' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:7' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:8' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:9' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:10' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:11' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:12' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:13' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:14' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:15' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:16' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:17' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:18' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:19' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:20' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:21' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:22' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:23' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:24' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:25' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:26' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:27' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:28' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:29' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:30' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:31' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:32' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:33' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:34' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:35' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:36' shape=(None,) dtype=int32>]
```

---

```
import random
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np

import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

# nltk.download('punkt')

# nltk.download('wordnet')

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import *
import keras
from keras import layers

import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'  # negates the version error caused by the CPU types

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['?', '!', '.', ',']

for intent in intents['intents']:
for pattern in intent['patterns']:
word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
words.extend(word_list)
documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
if intent['tag'] not in classes:
classes.append(intent['tag'])

words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in ignore_letters]
words = sorted(set(words))

classes = sorted(set(classes))

pickle.dump(words, open('words.pkl', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(words, open('classes.pkl', 'wb'))

training = []
output_empty = [0] * len(classes)

for document in documents:
bag = []
word_patterns = document[0]
word_patterns = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word.lower()) for word in word_patterns]
for word in words:
bag.append(1) if word in word_patterns else bag.append(0)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(document[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, output_row])

data_tensor = tf.ragged.constant(training)  
data_tensor = data_tensor.to_tensor()

random.shuffle(data_tensor)

data_tensor = np.array(data_tensor)

train_x = list(data_tensor[:, 0])
train_y = list(data_tensor[:, 1])

# train_x = np.array(train_x, dtype=int)

# train_y = np.array(train_y, dtype=int)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

# lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(

# initial_learning_rate=0.01,

# decay_steps=10000,

# decay_rate=0.9)

# optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule)

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=True, weight_decay=None, global_clipnorm=None, ema_momentum=0.99, ema_overwrite_frequency=None, name='SGD',)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accurancy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=5, epochs=10, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot_model.model')

print("\nDone\n")

model.load('chatbot_model.model')
```

---

Building the program I have a json file with an array of words taking them and splitting them through the code above and adding them into the neural network. I think that I haven't actually grasped the way the library tensorflow works and I tried many things in order to fix that, though it didn't help.

---

The json file contains an array build in this kind of a way, only bigger in content:

```
{"intents":  [
{"tag": "greetings",
"patterns": ["hello", "hey", "hi", "good day", "Greetings", "what's up?", "how is it going?"],
"responses": ["Hello!", "Hey!", "What can I do for you?"]
},

{"tag": "goodbye",
"patterns": ["cya", "See you later", "Goodbye", "I am Leaving", "Have a Good day", "bye", "cao", "see ya"],
"responses": ["Sad to see you go :(", "Talk to you later", "Goodbye!"]
},

{"tag": "name",
"patterns": ["what is your name", "what should i call you", "what should i call you", "what your name?", "who are you?", "who are you?", "can you tell me your name"],
"responses": ["Hello!", "Hey!", "What can I do for you?"]
}
]}
```

---

I am stack on this for quite a while and I dont know what else to try. Could you help me by proposing some ideas on how I can solve Value error problem mentioned above?
Thanks, for your help on whoever replies.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem. After the

```
data_tensor = np.array(data_tensor)

train_x = list(data_tensor[:, 0])
train_y = list(data_tensor[:, 1])
```

Instead of

```
train_x = np.array(train_x, dtype=int)

train_y = np.array(train_y, dtype=int)
```

which I had it unused at that time with #

I could use it without datatypes

```
train_x = np.array(train_x, dtype=int)

train_y = np.array(train_y, dtype=int)
```

Furthermore because the    `model.load` is a deprecated function nowadays it must be replaces with model = `tf.keras.models.load_model('chatbot_model.model')` and it runs just fine.